# Force Visual Studio 2013 to reload the project's .user file

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, msbuild

I am currently working on a tool that modifies the `<LocalDebuggerEnvironment>` of a `<project>.vcxproj.user` file.

After the changes, when VisualStudio is open, the changes will not be displayed in the project settings (i guess they get only loaded when the project is openend).

Is there any way to force Visual Studio to reload these settings?

/edit:
it might work to modify the project file to trigger the 'reload project' dialog but this feels not like a clean solution

Comment: I suspect "Unload Project" followed by "Reload Project". By default Visual Studio does some creative caching to improve performance. Turning that off may also do magic for you: http://blog.jessehouwing.nl/2012/06/just-in-time-updating-of-source-files.html

Comment: @jessehouwing "will grab the files from the in-memory cache" burries the hope of just being a UI problem

Comment: There's probably a way to notify the Build Host that the file has changed to prompt a reload, but I suspect it's a much better idea to use the Visual Studio Automation (envDTE) to modify the in memory settings and then force a save, than to modify the files under the nose if VS in the hopes it will pick up the changes.

Comment: This problem continues to repro even in Visual Studio 2022.

Answer (score 0):

ok, i found a solution for that.

i will create a VsAddin and implement the logic of my tool into it. So i can react to build events and set the variables needed way more simple than editing the vcxproj file from outside.